# cpp win7 console without scrollbars

Tags: c++, console, scrollbar, qbasic

I'd like to remove the scrollbars from my console (like in the `edit`-command) because i want to make a qbasic-like program. I know that here is [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471520/how-to-remove-scrollbars-in-console-windows-c) but it does not work for me in *windows 7 32bit*. There is written that you only have to make the console screen buffer the same size as the console window.
This dont work:

```
HANDLE hstdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hstdout, &csbi);

csbi.dwSize.X = csbi.srWindow.Right;
csbi.dwSize.Y = csbi.srWindow.Bottom;
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hstdout, csbi.dwSize);
```

Even if i set `csbi.dwSize.X` and `Y` to 10 or smaller, the scrollbars are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the size information contained in `srWindow` is for the the screen buffer not the actual window. You want to use `dwMaximumWindowSize` which specifies the size of the window in columns and rows.

```
csbi.dwSize.X = csbi.dwMaximumWindowSize.X;
csbi.dwSize.Y = csbi.dwMaximumWindowSize.Y;
```