# C++ How to remove vertical scrollbar?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to make a fun program where it display random numbers, but I need to remove the scrollbar so it looks more convincing. I managed to make the program full screen but I can't remove the vertical scrollbar. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUSN7.png)

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, 0);
    int output;
    bool done = false;
    system("color a");
    while (!done) {
        output = 1 + (rand() % (int)(1000 - 1 + 1));
        cout << output;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could clear the screen when it gets full, so a scroll bar never has a chance to show.

Comment: Do you know a way of doing that?

Comment: There's multiple ways of clearing a console, but which ways work depend on the console bring used. `system("cls")` will clear the screen, but I'll probably get yelled at for even suggesting you use `system`.  Also, you can look up ANSI escape codes. One of the clears the screen.

Comment: Take a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/1108489/how-to-remove-scrollbar-in-cmd-windows-10

Comment: And here if you want to do it with code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471520/how-to-remove-scrollbars-in-console-windows-c

Comment: When I try to user the code I get this error:     SetConsoleScreenBufferSize() failed! Reason : 87
Screen Buffer Size : 120 x 9001

Comment: Looks like you are not properly using function `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()`, post the new failing code in order to solve the issue. BTW if screen Y size is 9001 you have a super Monitor resolution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, one of them is manipulating the size of the internal buffer of the console to have the same size of the window and then using `ShowScrollBar` function to remove the scrolls.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, 0);

    HANDLE hstdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hstdout, &csbi);

    csbi.dwSize.X = csbi.dwMaximumWindowSize.X;
    csbi.dwSize.Y = csbi.dwMaximumWindowSize.Y;
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hstdout, csbi.dwSize);

    HWND x = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowScrollBar(x, SB_BOTH, FALSE);

    int output;
    bool done = false;
    system("color a");

    while (!done) {
        output = 1 + (rand() % (int)(1000 - 1 + 1));
        cout << output;

    }
}
```

Another way is to rely on conio.h or another C/C++ header/library which implements user interface functions.